# Can I use "replace someone with someone or something else"?

Tags: expressions, idioms, idiom-requests

Suppose you're talking to someone (or you're doing something with someone). You're quite passionate about the conversation or, in general, the situation. Say, at a certain point, the phone of the person you're talking to rings or, in general, a "new thing" happens. Your interlocutor decides to stop the conversation with you and do something else with that person on the phone or to simply stop doing what she or he was doing with you (because of the new thing).

Can I say "You feel bad or mistreated when someone replaces you with someone or something else" in these circumstances? Is "replace with" the most idiomatic expression? Does it even make sense? I think this type of situation is quite common among teenagers, so there should be such an expression. What would be the most idiomatic expression?

**Note**: *I am not talking about the specific case of "dumping a person" (who's your partner). I would like to have an expression that describes this **general** kind of situations, i.e. you feel irrelevant, mistreated and, indeed, "replaced with or for something or someone else".*

Comment: I’d say, *when someone interrupts your phone conversation  to answer another call.*

Comment: @user070221 No. It was just an example! I would like to have an idiomatic expression that describes this type of general situations.

Comment: *Interrupt* sounds pretty generic.

Comment: @Lawrence But it doesn't imply that you feel mistreated or "replaced".

Comment: I thought you wanted something idiomatic for “replace with”. The “feel ... mistreated” part conveys the emotion. *interrupt* deals with the ‘mechanics’ of the matter. (Also, interruptions tend to be annoying to many people in any case.)

Comment: @Lawrence Interrupt is not the verb I am looking for. In any case, I want to be explicit: I want to say "Replace someone with _someone else_".

Comment: If you want to keep the word “replace”, which bit are you looking to change?

Comment: @Lawrence I would like to know if that expression is idiomatic, as I asked in my question ;)

Comment: Not really, if by *idiomatic* you mean *in common usage*. But it conveys the sense pretty well. (I’m stopping here to avoid getting pulled up for being too chatty.)

Comment: @Lawrence Last questions. 1) Are you an English native speaker?, 2) Should I use "with" or "for" after "replace" (or "replaced") in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The situation you are discribing could be best expressed by the verb **[to ignore](https://www.bing.com/search?q=define%20to%20ignore&pc=MOZI&form=MOZSBR)**. There isn't necessarily here the explicit assertion that their interest is now consumed by something else, but that is reasonably assumed, as otherwise they would sit vapidly staring off into the distance like a goldfish.

> **ignore**: obsolete ignore to be ignorant of, from French ignorer, from Latin ignorare, from ignarus ignorant, unknown, from in- + gnoscere, noscere to know — more at know

This would also capture the sentiment of "feel(ing) bad or mistreated", as "ignore," in so far as humans are concerned, elicits a rejection of the [Being](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Being_and_Time) or opinion of someone else (perhaps in preference of another)

---

EDIT: To speak to @nbro's comment, you could also try **[substitute](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supplant)** or **supplant**, though these do not carry inherent negative sentiment ("supplant" comes close)-- and it should be noted neither does "replace". They are also unwieldy for describing behavior of *people*, I feel.

Comment: But I would like to specifically say that a person "replaces you with _something_ or _someone_" and not that she simply "ignored" you, which, I think, is not explicit about what actually happened. For example, you can ignore e.g. a problem without that strictly implying that you're going to solve another problem instead.

Answer (score 0):

**put someone on hold** [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+on+hold) idiom

**Fig. to stop all activity or communication with someone.**

As in:

John put her on hold and started talking to Mary. "You can't just put me on hold!" cried Ann.